# Timeline Posts are not being displayed

Tags: flutter

My timeline page is not displaying any posts of users which I'm following. The posts are working fine on the user's profile page but not showing up on timeline. Here is the code of my timeline, and I don't see any debug errors too, so how to identify what's wrong here? Did I miss something? However, for the new user sign up, it does show users to follow on the timeline page.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/search.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/header.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/post.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/progress.dart';

class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
  final User currentUser;

  Timeline({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {
  List<Post> posts;
  List<String> followingList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTimeline();
    getFollowing();
  }

  getTimeline() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await timelineRef
        .document(widget.currentUser.id)
        .collection('timelinePosts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();

    List<Post> posts =
        snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }

  getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
        .document(currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .getDocuments();

    setState(() {
      followingList = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
    });
  }

  buildTimeline() {
    if (posts == null) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else if (posts.isEmpty) {
      return buildUsersToFollow();
    } else {
      return ListView(children: posts);
    }
  }

  buildUsersToFollow() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream:
          usersRef.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).limit(30).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<UserResult> userResults = [];
        snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
          User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
          final bool isAuthUser = currentUser.id == user.id;
          final bool isFollowingUser = followingList.contains(user.id);
          if (isAuthUser) {
            return;
          } else if (isFollowingUser) {
            return;
          } else {
            UserResult userResult = UserResult(user);
            userResults.add(userResult);
          }
        });
        return Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.2),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.person_add,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Users to Follow",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(children: userResults),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, isAppTitle: true),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => getTimeline(),
        child: buildTimeline(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code

```
buildTimeline() {
  if (posts == null) {
    return circularProgress();
  } else if (posts.isEmpty) {
    return buildUsersToFollow();
  } else {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: posts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return Text(posts[index].toString);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: return Text(posts[index]); it gives error on this line on posts index. and says: The argument type 'Post' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: Should be .toString() and no, its still the same. Circular Progress is revolving only...

Answer (score 0):

ListView takes Widgets as a children. posts is not a widgets of any kind.

Comment: List<Post> posts =
        snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();

Comment: Try this in ListView, return Text(posts[index].postId);